# Запись значений исходя из множества условий

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Имею:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 'column2': [100, 100, 500], 'column3': [100, '', 400]}) 
df
```

На выходе:

```
  column1  column2  column3
0   name1      100      100
1   name2      100      
2   name3      500      400
```

**Задача:**

В новую `column4` вывести:

- "Условие_1" **если** column1 = name1 **и** column2 = column3
- "Условие_2" **если** column1 = name2 **или** name3 **и** column2 > column3
- "Значение пропущено" **если** в column2 или column3 есть пустота
- "Пропустить" во всех других случаях

Вот, что хочу получить:

```
  column1  column2  column3     column4
0   name1      100      100  Услоавие_1
1   name2      100           Значение пропущено
2   name3      500      400  Услоавие_2
```

Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ, т.к. мои попытки решить не увенчались даже кусочком рабочего кода.

Какой вариант оптимальней будет применить? В обучающих статьях и ответах на аналогичные вопросы применяют разные методы.

Моя попытка решения:

```
df['column4'] = apply.[lambda x: "Условие_1" if x == 'name1' and df['column2']=df['column3'] else 'пропустить' for x in df['column1']]
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе попытки решения, которые не увенчались успехом

Comment: самое простое решение "в лоб" будет состоять из четырех `df.loc[...] = ...` команд

Comment: И еще можете уточнить тип данных столбца `column3`? В приведенном примере он строкового типа из-за значения `''` - как обстоят дела с вашими реальными данными? Я спрашиваю потому что из-за этой "мелочи" не будет работать сравнение `column2 > column3`

Comment: @MaxU В column3 будет datetime64.

 Один из моих примеров решения состоял в этом (я знаю, что это капец:) )
df['column4'] = apply.[lambda x: "Условие_1" if x == 'name1' and df['column2']=df['column3'] else 'пропустить' for x in df['column1']] 
Оно ломается на первом же условии

так же пробовал делать через селектнампая, но тоже не вышло

Comment: Добавил, если нужно я могу прикрепить еще, я пробовал через selecr numpy, но совсем не получилось

причем получается делать со строковым значениями, но если я работаю с датафреймом то множество условий уже не работает

Comment: можете добавить воспроизводимый пример данных (я имею ввиду данные для `column3`)? В ваших реальных данных - пустые строки или `NaN` / `NaT` ?

Comment: NaT, column2 и column3 это значения datetime64
сейчас попробую добавить

Comment: @Dikson Опять вы внутри лямбды сравниваете `df`, а не `x`

Comment: ой, грубая ошибка, спасибо!

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Входной фрейм (обратите внимание на `NaN` вместо `''` во второй строке):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  column1  column2  column3
0   name1      100    100.0
1   name2      100      NaN
2   name3      500    400.0
```

решение (орфография авторов для значений строк сохранена):

```
df.loc[df.query("column1 == 'name1' and column2 == column3").index, "column4"] = "Услоавие_1"

df.loc[df.query("column1 in ('name2', 'name3') and column2 > column3").index, "column4"] = "Услоавие_2"

df.loc[df["column2"].isna() | df["column3"].isna(), "column4"] = "Значение пропущено"
```

результат:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
  column1  column2  column3             column4
0   name1      100    100.0          Услоавие_1
1   name2      100      NaN  Значение пропущено
2   name3      500    400.0          Услоавие_2
```